# vue.js&laravel what's the proper way to set up different environments

Tags: laravel, vue.js, architecture

I have a front-end in vue.js and back-end API in laravel. I am curious about environments. I will write down my idea and let me know if it's the right one.

we could have `development`, `staging` and `production` environments. So this means front-end will need 2 servers. 1 for staging, 1 for production. For API, we also need 2 servers. staging server will have different database and production will have different database. So 4 servers overal.

So do you think 4 servers are a way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You just need 2 actually. Staging and development's front-end should come with the API. Then production's front-end and API should come together. You don't really need separate servers for back-end and front-end, just separate environments. Also it will depend on how you will set it up. In fact, all can go in one server in different docker containers.